# MS Access ADO connection string with Failover Partner option

Tags: ms-access, vba, connection-string

Is it possible to use an ADO connection string in VBA Access with `failover partner` option included?

My connection code looks something like this:

```
Public Function OpenADOConnection() As Boolean
On Error GoTo err_trap

' Opens Global ADO Connection if it isnt already open.
' Returns TRUE if connected

          Dim boolState As Boolean

    If gcnn Is Nothing Then
          Set gcnn = New ADODB.Connection ' if the global has not been instantiated or has been destroyed
      End If

     If gcnn.state = adStateOpen Then
         boolState = True ' already open, nothing else to do
     Else
         gcnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=SQL01;Failover Partner=SQL02;Initial Catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True"
       gcnn.Open
       If gcnn.state = adStateOpen Then
           boolState = True
       Else
            boolState = False ' cannot open connection so return false
       End If
    End If

    OpenADOConnection = boolState ' return the connection state

exit_here:
    Exit Function

err_trap:
    OpenADOConnection = False
    Call MsgBox("Unable to connect to the database. Please notify Database Administrator!" & vbCrLf & _
              "(This error CANNOT be logged!", vbCritical, "ADO Connection Failed:", "", 0)
200       Resume exit_here

End Function
```

Currently, it fails to open the connection so I'm not sure what I'm missing or even if it's possible to achieve this.

Essentially I want the connection to automatically failover without user interference and knowledge.

Comment: Can you provide the error?

Comment: Just says `Overflow` nothing else which isn't much help at all.

Comment: Does it work with just `Data Source=SQL02;` - with no Failover Partner defined?

Comment: Yes without failover it works fine

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `Provider` being defined anywhere in your connection string. That is a general problem.

I never used the failover options with ADO, but I'm pretty sure the old OLE DB Provider (`SQLOLEDB`) does not support them. Instead you should use the brand new [`Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (msoledbsql)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).